# Why is this solution in codewars Multiplication table for number not working?

Tags: python-3.x

The task is:
Your goal is to return multiplication table for number that is always an integer from 1 to 10.

For example, a multiplication table (string) for number == 5 looks like below:

```
1 * 5 = 5
2 * 5 = 10
3 * 5 = 15
4 * 5 = 20
5 * 5 = 25
6 * 5 = 30
7 * 5 = 35
8 * 5 = 40
9 * 5 = 45
10 * 5 = 50
```

My code:

```
def multi_table(number):
    for num in range(1,11):
        print (str(num) + " * " + str(number) + " = " + str(num * number))
   

user = int(input("Your number: "))
print(multi_table(user))
```

Here is what comes up:

```
1 * 5 = 5
2 * 5 = 10
3 * 5 = 15
4 * 5 = 20
5 * 5 = 25
6 * 5 = 30
7 * 5 = 35
8 * 5 = 40
9 * 5 = 45
10 * 5 = 50
None should equal '1 * 5 = 5\n2 * 5 = 10\n3 * 5 = 15\n4 * 5 = 20\n5 * 5 = 25\n6 * 5 = 30\n7 * 5 = 35\n8 * 5 = 40\n9 * 5 = 45\n10 * 5 = 50'
```

Comment: can u please explain what is ur error?

Answer (score 0):

So the online judge seems to be checking for what you **return** and not what you **print**. So why don't you try replacing the print statement with return statement in your function definition and see if it works.

```py
def multi_table(number):
    out = ""
    for num in range(1,11):
        out += (str(num) + " * " + str(number) + " = " + str(num * number))
    return out
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it only returns the first line, because the "return" exits the for loop, so 2-9 will not be returned.

Comment: def multi_table(number):
    out = ""
    for num in range(1,11):
        out += (str(num) + " * " + str(number) + " = " + str(num * number))
    return out

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this and it work somehow. I tweak @Anand Narayanan original code and below is the new code:

```
def multi_table(number):
    out = ""
    for num in range(1,11):
        out += (str(num) + " * " + str(number) + " = " + str(num * number ) + "\n")
    return out.strip()
```

I only added the `"\n"` and strip method on the `out` string.